# How to convert seconds to mm:ss format of string in UWP?

Tags: uwp

I want to convert time value like 71 seconds to mm:ss format, which means 1:11
(note that not 01:11 here), how to do it?

Another example is converting 612 seconds to 10:12.

My method is to calculate:

```
612 / 60 = 10
612 % 60 = 12
```

And combine the result with : between them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TimeSpan and it will convert those seconds into minutes and seconds for you.

```
var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0,0,71);
```

And then you can use the Minutes and Seconds properties to display what you need:

```
string toDisplay = timeSpan.Minutes + ":" + timeSpan.Seconds;
```

edit:  The proper use of string formatting:

```
timeSpan.ToString(@"m\:ss");
```

Displays:

```
1:11
```